# How to export results in CSV UTF-8 instead of UTF-8 BOM

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:**

Is there a way to configure settings so that when results are exported into CSV when executing a query, the output is dumped in a UTF-8 format instead of UTF-8 bom?

Comment: It's probably easier to configure the tool that consumes the CSV to ignore the BOM than to configure SSIS not to create it.

Comment: @Tomalak, there isn't any way to configure my settings to remove the BOM? im currently doing it in Notepad+ but I'd like to skpi this step.

Comment: What's the specific problem you have with the BOM?

Comment: its my client that requests the file to exclude BOM @Tomalak

Comment: And you're exporting the file... manually? If that's the case, Notepad++ can absolutely save the file as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: yes @Tomalak , that is what i'm currently doing but my question whether or not there is a setting inside sql server that would do what notepad does.

Comment: See first comment. Read it as "I cannot imagine there is, and you should look for alternative approaches."

Comment: Another example when CSV import fails due to BOM is when using pgAdmin's import functionality which might fail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872987/how-to-remove-bom-byte-order-mark-in-csv-export-using-visual-studio-ssrs-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872987/how-to-remove-bom-byte-order-mark-in-csv-export-using-visual-studio-ssrs-2017

Answer (score 0):

One way to circumvent this is to use SSMS' Import and Export wizard which is more tedious as it requires to introduce the whole context (connection and query).

Select to export to a flat file and set locale = UTF-8 (locale = 65001), double-check that Unicode is not checked and select the source as a custom query.

Note: after having a large export (> 1M records) messed up even by the method above, I have switched to a modern client to export the data ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47515548/2780791)).

Answer (score -1):

this is answered in another question

[How to remove BOM (Byte Order Mark) in CSV export using visual studio SSRS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872987/how-to-remove-bom-byte-order-mark-in-csv-export-using-visual-studio-ssrs-2017)

You will have to stop/start the service for this to take effect.

remember to back up the config file so you can restore it if the server crashes!

Comment: The right way to point readers to another question that has the answer is to vote to close as duplicate, not to post an answer with the link. That question however is not a duplicate of this one because it talks about Visual Studio rather than SSMS.

Comment: i dont see that the op specified SSMS. He tagged sql server, of which SSRS is a part, and of which ssms is a part. I posted the link b/c this question did not help me , but the other one did. So I took a few minutes to help someone else follow a path that ultimately helped me. How I long for the old days when people came to SO w the intent to help, instead of nitpick.   Thanks for the comment and the downvote.