# How to remove BOM (Byte Order Mark) in CSV export using visual studio SSRS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, export-to-csv, byte-order-mark

When I export data to CSV file using SSRS 2017 I got BOM (Byte Order Mark) in the data. 
How can I get rid of it?

I tried the below link, but I cannot find `rsreportserver.config` file

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43747563-bf27-4881-89ab-3c140b9459be/edit-reportserverconfig-to-prevent-bom-being-displayed-in-csv-export?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 1):

We added a new render in the :\Program Files\Microsoft Reporting Services\SSRS\Report Server\rsreportserver.config its in the selectable list of save options and you can rename it

```
<Extension Name="CSVASCII" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
    <Configuration>
        <DeviceInfo>
            <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
        </DeviceInfo>
    </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

This forces ASCII encoding removing the BOM (´╗┐)

We have others for XML and TEXT (PIPE "|") output, we found it better to add than to override.

Answer (score 0):

Adam Marshall's answer above is right on. (Just note that you must add an `</Extension>` closing tag at the end.)

On my server, the rsreportserver.config file was in this folder:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer

Answer (score 0):

```
<Extension Name="CSVASCII" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
<OverrideNames>
                     <Name Language="en-US">CSV (ASCII)</Name>
               </OverrideNames>
    <Configuration>
        <DeviceInfo>
            <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
        </DeviceInfo>
    </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

it was necessary for me to add the name over ride, or i got two CSV  options.

you can also put visible="false" inside the Extension tag

I can not find anything on ms.com about configuring these, I did find this article
that shows the name override
https://blog.iatric.com/report-writing-blog/adding-pipe-delimited-option-to-ssrs-export-destinations