# DBeaver Exporting to CSV

Tags: export-to-csv, dbeaver

I am in the need of switching from Aginity Workbench to something else for a redshift database [read only user], i was suggested DBeaver

i have searched google in many ways but cannot find a way to Export a result set to CSV without manually running the script then exporting.
With Aginity, i could run exports from command line [Opens and Copies a SQL File resultset directly to CSV], and batch then up [around 150 or so extracts each morning, so manually running would take too long]

Does DBeaver have similar functionality? even if its just a copy to csv sql script i can run from inside DBeaver as a select query [which i do currently with postgres]

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47515548/12488391

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It does and follow below.

Right click on table(Redshift or Azure)

[image]

You can select the format(.csv or any listed below format) of output file as shown in below
[image]